# How to properly pass data with Ajax with CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I want to create a dynamic map with checkbox to customize the marker on the map.
Of course i use Ajax for that, well i would like to use it :)

My ajax call is ok, i pass the data from the view to the controller with :

```
$( "input[type=checkbox]" ).click(function() {
  var data = $(this).val();
  var request = $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "<?php echo site_url(current_url());?>",
  data: "categorie=" + data,
});
request.done (function(data){
  var json = data;
  // Remove the markers and add new ones
```

I pass the data to the controller and treat it like this

```
    if ($this->input->is_ajax_request()) {
        $category = $_POST['categorie'];
        $unsigned_url = "http://api.yelp.com/v2/search?location=" . $data->home['city']['cities_name'] . "&category_filter=" . $category;
        $new_JSON = $this->listing_lib->getJsonFromYelp($unsigned_url);
        echo $new_JSON;
    }
```

the problem is, in the json variable in the JS i got the JSON from the PHP but i also get all the DOM of the page?
Why that ? how can i get only my JSON ?

Comment: Just put `exit()` after `echo $new_JSON;` but still inside the if statement.  It stops the page sending any further response.

Comment: Try this `echo $new_JSON;die();`

Comment: have you checked that what is a response from your $this->listing_lib->getJsonFromYelp($unsigned_url); ?

Comment: Yep, i use this function when i load the page, it returns a valid JSON

Comment: @Archer The exit solution works! Just wondering if there is a more 'clean' solution to this ?

Comment: That's exactly what it's for - it just ends the page response and returns.  If you wanted something "cleaner" then maybe consider putting ajax calls in different php files, rather than pages that can be browsed to, but it works so why not.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $( "input[type=checkbox]" ).click(function() {
    var data = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "<?php echo site_url(current_url());?>",
      data: {"categorie":data},
      dataType:"json",
      cache: false
      success: function (categorie) {
        /// your code for show category
     }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($this->input->is_ajax_request()) {
    $category = $_POST['categorie'];
    $unsigned_url = "http://api.yelp.com/v2/search?location=" . $data->home['city']['cities_name'] . "&category_filter=" . $category;
    $new_JSON = $this->listing_lib->getJsonFromYelp($unsigned_url);
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    print_r json_encode($new_JSON);
}
```

This should be better.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
$( "input[type=checkbox]" ).click(function() {
       var data = $(this).val();
       var request = $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "<?php echo site_url(current_url());?>",
       data: "categorie=" + data,
       dataType:"json",
       success:function(response){
         alert(response);

       }
});
```

and in controller

```
if ($this->input->is_ajax_request()) {
    $category = $_POST['categorie'];
    $unsigned_url = "http://api.yelp.com/v2/search?location=" . $data->home['city']['cities_name'] . "&category_filter=" . $category;
    $new_JSON = $this->listing_lib->getJsonFromYelp($unsigned_url);
    print json_encode($new_JSON);
}
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: which DOM are you getting in response. You said that you use the same function to load this page? are you getting DOM of you own page or the DOM of the response link i.e "http://api.yelp.com/v2/search?location=" . $data->home['city']['cities_name'] . "&category_filter=" . $category;

Answer (score 0):

Before you output your json try to set output type and output:

```
    if ($this->input->is_ajax_request()) {
            $category = $_POST['categorie'];
            $unsigned_url = "http://api.yelp.com/v2/search?location=" 
            .$data->home['city']['cities_name'] . "&category_filter=" . $category;

            $new_JSON = $this->listing_lib->getJsonFromYelp($unsigned_url);
            $this->output->set_content_type('application/json'); 
            $this->output->set_output($new_JSON);  
    }
```